# How to get starting and end point of peaks in excel graph

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that will find a certain peak in a graph.

I want to write a macro or formula that tell me the starting and end point of specific peaks in this graph

Here is the image of the graph:
[image]

Here is the code I created:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim dl_input As Worksheet
    Set dl_input = wb.Worksheets("Graph")

    lastrow = dl_input.Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, 
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    lastrow = Int(lastrow / 5)
    
    Dim correlvalues() As Single
    ReDim correlvalues(lastrow - 13)
    
    Dim peaks() As Single
    ReDim peaks(lastrow - 13)
    
    Dim index() As Single
    ReDim index(lastrow - 13)
    
    Dim counting As Integer
    counting = 1
    
    Dim maxpeak As Single

    'Implement the correl function to the signal and its various lags
    For counter = 1 To lastrow - 13
        Debug.Print "Counter: " & counter & " Last Counter: " & lastrow - 13 & " Range1: " & range1 & " Range2: " & range2
        
        range1 = "D" & (11 + counter) & ":" & "D" & lastrow
        range2 = "D11:D" & (lastrow - counter)
        
        correlvalues(counter) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Correl(Range(range1), Range(range2))
    Next counter

    'Result is an array of the correl values, indicating how similar the
    'lagged version of the signal is to the original signal
    'Higher value means higher similarity, denoting pattern has repeated
    'for this frequency

    'Next is obtain peaks of the resulting graph
    For counter = 2 To lastrow - 14
        If correlvalues(counter) > correlvalues(counter - 1) And correlvalues(counter) > correlvalues(counter + 1) And correlvalues(counter) > 0 Then
            peaks(counting) = correlvalues(counter)
            index(counting) = counter
            counting = counting + 1
        End If
    Next counter

    'Highest peak will be the lag duration which is most similar to the
    'original signal. This will be the starting point of the next cycle
    
    '12 is subtracted since obtained value is starting point of next cycle,
    'subtract one to get duration and subtract 11 since data starts in row 11
    
    maxpeak = WorksheetFunction.Max(peaks)
    cycleduration = WorksheetFunction.Match(maxpeak, correlvalues, 0) - 12
    
    dl_input.Range("G1").Value = cycleduration
    
    'Obtain start and end rows of data based on user input (number of cylce)
    dl_start = 10 + (cycleduration * (TXT_COUNT.Text - 1))
    dl_end = dl_start + cycleduration
    
    dl_input.Activate
    dl_input.Range("D" & dl_start & ":" & "D" & dl_end).Copy
```

Macro:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ml0svxpgwno19d0p6wejy/macro.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=iuapfdw9aody3mel1nbamc5pb

Comment: What is your question? What does your code do? What is the issue in the code? You need a method to find the absolute minimum between 2 peaks. For example start of peak 5 is the absolute minimum between paek 4 and 5 and end of peak 5 is the absolute minimum between peak 5 and 6.  If you already have the peaks you can easily get those values with the `=Min()` formula or `WorksheetFunction.Min()` between 2 peaks.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the same method you used to finde the maxima (peaks) to find the minima. The minima left of a peak is then the start and right of a peak the end.

Comment: My question is how to find the range of start and end point of selected peaks.

Comment: For example to get the start and end of peak 5 find the position of that value in your cell range of values eg. search there for `index(5)` and `index(6)` then use `WorksheetFunktion.Min()` on the y-values of the range between `index(5)` and `index(6)` so you get the lowest value than use the `Match` function to find the position of the mininum value in your cell range and to find its x-value. This is the end of peak 5! then do the same with `index(4)` and `index(5)` and you get the beginning of peak 5.

Comment: It's hard to be more precise without the original raw data. Maybe you can provide some example data. If my explanation is too vague.